# Letter Keypad problem but with String Function(Java)

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, letter, keypad

I have been stuck on a recursion question. It is the letter keypad problem (**The problem is to print all possible combination from a number where numbers are related to alphabets in the same manner as that on a phone keypad**)! The reason why I am unable to solve it is that I am required to make a String function and I have no idea how i am gonna make it work! I have posted the 2 functions I made to solve this question but they are giving wrong answer.

Input : 23

Expected output: ad ae af bd be bf cd ce cf

Output I am getting : cf

```
final static char[][] codes = { {' ',' ',' '}, {' ',' ',' '}, {'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'}, 
                      {'g','h','i'}, {'j','k','l'}, {'m','n','o'}, 
                      {'p','q','r','s'}, {'t','u','v'}, {'w','x','y','z'}  }; 
//java
static char c[];

public static void printKeyWords(int num[] , int current , int n ) { 

    int i;
    if (current  == n) { 
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < codes[num[current]].length; i++) {        

        c[current] = codes[num[current]][i];
        printKeyWords(num , current +1 , n);
        if(num[current] == 0 || num[current] == 1)
                return;

    } 

}

// Return a string array that contains all the possible strings
public static String[] keypad(int input){
    String s= Integer.toString(input);
    int num [] = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        num[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    c = new char[num.length + 1];
    printKeyWords(num , 0 ,num.length);

    String str = new String(c);
    String strArray[] = str. split(" ");

    return strArray;
}
```

Comment: Show me input and output you want, plz

Comment: Could you please describe the 'letter keypad problem' in your text?

Comment: When you set the last character (when current is equal to n minus one), you need to record that as a solution. You are only looking at the solution after the recursion is over, so you will only see the last solution. Also, there is no reason to split the string. Also, why is `c` sized as `num.length + 1`? What is that `+ 1` for? Also, you need a `List<String>` to append solutions to. You don't know in advance how many solutions there are going to be. (In theory you could calculate that number; in practice, just use a `List` and add to it.)

Comment: @DavidConrad I am sorry but I am still a novice. so I have no Idea how to use `List<String>`.Hence I am having a huge problem coz this was and old code I found off the internet. I tried to salvage every bit I can so there are some pieces which I myself dont know but I left them there hoping they work

Comment: @NomadMaker The problem is to print all possible combination from a number where numbers are related to alphabets in the same manner as that on a phone keypad

Comment: @LêHoàngDững Input : 23                                                             Expected Output
ad
bd
cd
ae
be
ce
af
bf
cf

Comment: Oh ! I am so sorry ! I'll do it right away @ggorlen

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the cases to find combinations, whenever n == num.lengh print out the combination.

```
static int[] num;

public static String printKeyWords(int n, String s){
    if (n == num.length) {
        return s + " ";
    }
    String temp = "";
    for (int j = 0; j<codes[num[n]].length; j++){
        temp += printKeyWords(n+1, s+ codes[num[n]][j]);
    }
    return temp;
}

public static String[] keypad(int input){
    String s= Integer.toString(input);
    num = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        num[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return printKeyWords(0,"").split(" ");
}
```

Instead of int num [] you should int [] num will be more readable

Comment: Thanks for your effort.. But according to the question I have , `public static void keypad(int input)` should be a `String[] ` function not  `void`